# LDAP Active Directory find all users from two OU

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I want to find all users which are contained in two OUs, but not in the other ones. Basically, this is the same issue as in https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/ExtensibleMatch#section-ExtensibleMatch-SearchWithinTwoContainers, but within an Active Directory.
The page there says "Microsoft Active Directory does NOT support this functionality and only supports: Microsoft Active Directory Extensible Match Rules".

I want to find all users from within the OUs Administration and People as in:

```
dc=com
    dc=willeke
        ou=Administration
            cn=OneInetOrgPerson
            ....
        ou=People
            cn=TwoInetOrgPerson
            ....
            ou=butler
               cn=moreInetOrgPerson
               ....
        ou=Groups
            cn=ThreeInetOrgPerson
            ....
        ou=IDM
            cn=FourInetOrgPerson
            ....
        ou=Sales
            cn=FiveInetOrgPerson
            ....
```

I do not understand how to create this same functionality with Active Directory. Is this even possible with an AD?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this with PowerShell.

```
Import-Module Active Directory
$OUs = 'OU=Administration,DC=willeke,DC=com','OU=People 2,DC=willeke,DC=com'
$OUs | ForEach { Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_ }
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8354b35a-e4f8-428b-918f-a10ab3efa5d0/getaduser-effective-multiou-search?forum=winserverpowershell

https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28788079/Get-Users-from-multiple-OUs-with-Poweshell.html

Answer (score 2):

As user5870571 pointed out, you can perform two separate queries and combine the results.

Alternatively, you can change your search scope to a higher level container and filter your results on the client side.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'DC=willeke,DC=com' | 
    Where-Object { $_.distinguishedName -like '*,OU=Administration,DC=willeke,DC=com' -or
                   $_.distinguishedName -like '*,OU=People,DC=willeke,DC=com' }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to connect an application to the AD and fetch the users via LDAP. I tried the above query but did not a get result. I think I'll try again.

Comment: The filter in the example won't work because it's Powershell specific. Your application would need to support something similar or you need to find another way like a group membership to distinguish the users in those OUs.